# jQuery datatables - Uncaught TypeError: a.charAt is not a function

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am trying to integrate datatables jQuery plugin into my table generated through PHP.

The table layout and everything looks fine with search and sorting options but when clicking on any sorting options in table headers I am facing this error

> Uncaught TypeError: a.charAt is not a function

Did anyone face this problem before? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps show some code?

Comment: And what file it is causing the error - as I'm guessing that's appearing in the console.

Answer (score 7):

Datatable bug connected with changes in empty string processing by map function.
Fixed in some code I saw.

Quick fix in my case was to replace `match(/"[^"]+"|[^ ]+/g)||''` with `match(/"[^"]+"|[^ ]+/g)||['']` (empty value as array) in datatable code.

Answer (score 4):

This issue existed (at least) on Datatables 1.10.5, but no longer on 1.10.16, so it has been since fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because either you have multiple jQuery loaded in the same page or you are loading datatable before loading jQuery.

To resolve the issue:

- Make sure only 1 jQuery is loaded
- Load jQuery first then the datatable (Order matters)

Comment: I checked the order and looks fine, jQuery was loaded before loading datatable.

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: It is jQuery v1.12.4

Comment: Which datatable version are you using? Could you please paste the code to show how it's beeing loaded?

Comment: I get this error when using jquery-3.1.1.js - 

I don't get it when using jquery-2.1.3.js

Comment: Which version of DataTable are you using? Did you make sure that multiple jquery are not loaded?